# No Line Breaks with Text file with asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I want to read a text file and load its content to my page. I was trying to read the file with StreamReader and then assign the text to a Label, but the text in the page is just one line. I mean the line in the text file wasn't viewed in the page. What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps tackling a symptom rather than the problem itself, you can wrap the text file's contents within a `<PRE>` tag wherein, unlike most other content in HTML, whitespace is respected.

Answer (score 1):

The textfile uses \n or \r\n for getting new lines (\n is a newline and \r is a carriage return - back in the day of typewritters you had to pull the bar thingy back to the left which is called a carriage return and roll the paper down a line to start on the left side of a newline-). Windows generally uses \r\n (although it depends on the application that created the file) mac's generally use \n.

HTML on the other hand uses the `<br/`> tag for new lines (if you do a viewsource on your current html output you will see the newlines). So all you need to do is replace \r\n or with 
. You can do this with:

```
yourstring = yourstring.Replace("\r\n", "<br/>");
```

or if you don't know for sure what's used in the file or both \r\n and \n are used you can use

```
yourstring = yourstring.Replace("\r\n", "<br/>").Replace("\n", "<br/>");
```

be aware that a string is immutable and thus methods like Replace return a copy of the string that has the replacements made. The original string will stay intact.

Comment: thanks olle
that's what I was looking for
another small question....
can I get the text format from the file 
for example(font size,bold,color...)

Comment: generally yes but it depends on what the format of the document is in (.rtf, .doc) etc...  how much effort it will be and it can get complex fast. In general you want to find a library or something that does this for you.

Comment: @Hany:  Ordinary text files contain no such information as font, bold and color.  So what file format exactly are you actually reading.  Please place that detail in your question.

Comment: actually I have tried with word file(I add a spiceal reference for that) I can read from the file but the problem is about format
it doesn't appear

Comment: thats a confusing response. It's not really an answer nor a question. And didn't you want formatting? Now you complain about formatting being left intact? I think it's best to create a new question properly stating the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

if (System.IO.File.Exists(Server.MapPath("test.txt")))

```
    {
        System.IO.StreamReader StreamReader1 = new
```

System.IO.StreamReader(Server.MapPath("test.txt"));

```
        lblMyLabel.Text= StreamReader1.ReadToEnd();

        StreamReader1.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML doesn't recognize white-space (line breaks, etc) in your text file.  If you want to render the content as HTML, you'll need to convert line-breaks into `<br/`> tags.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
string path = 'c:\myfile.txt':
lblMyLabel.Text = String.Join('<br/>', File.ReadAllLines(path));
```